# Seeking records of ancestor born in Lemberg/Lviv (Ukraine) in 1913?

Tags: 20th-century, birth-records, ukraine

My family and I are trying to find official records of my late grandmother. She was born in Lemberg in 1913. 
First name: Bronislawa/Bertha
Last name: Barth/Halpern

I tried https://search.geshergalicia.org/ but couldn't find anything.

Where else should I look?

Answer (score 3):

According to http://jri-poland.org/psa/status.htm#AGAD, Lemberg/Lwow/Lviv births for 1913 do not appear in LDS (Mormon) microfilms, and there is ongoing fundraising for a project to create an index of birth, marriage, and death records for that city for a number of years including 1913 births.

Search for Lwow on that page to find more information, including the name and email address of the person coordinating the project.

It's also possible that you might be able to contact the archive which holds those records, either directly or through a researcher you hire, to search the records. Keep in mind that birth years listed in various documents (aside from original birth records) often aren't exact, as people might not have known their birth year or might have chosen to report a different year than they knew they were born. This certainly can apply to census records.

(Note that there may be alternate records which can help you find the information you're looking for. For instance, if you want to know the names of your grandmother's parents, the death record for her or one of her siblings might tell you those names.)

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. Where can i find a qualified researcher? We have quite a bit of info actually including the exact spelling of her name, her parents names, their date of birth, place of births, etc. On her father's death papers it says she was born in Lemberg although her family lived in Graz. Would they have written it as Lemberg in the 1920s? I just want to make sure this is the same is Lviv which is in Ukraine today.

Comment: Also which archives should we contact to ask about such records? My Grandmother was jewish.

Comment: The directory of the Association of Professional Genealogists (APG) is here: https://www.apgen.org/directory/search.html?type=advanced&new_search=true With the advanced search, you can search by research specialty as well as geographic specialty.